# CosmosDb Parameterized Query using GUID

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, prepared-statement

Using nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.29.0`

I'm attempting to use a parameterized query against CosmosDB and can't figure out the syntax to make this case work.

The data in CosmosDblooks like

```json
{
    "body": {
        "INTERNAL-GUID": {
            "myValue": 6
        }
    },
    "id": "someGuid"
    ...
}
```

This query definition works.

```
new QueryDefinition($"SELECT f.myValue FROM c JOIN c.body['{strInternalGuid}'] as f where c.id='SomeGuid'");
```

These parameterized versions do not.

```
new QueryDefinition("SELECT f.myValue FROM c JOIN c.body[\"@internalId\"] as f where c.id='SomeGuid'");
query.WithParameter("@internalId", strInternalGuid);
...
new QueryDefinition("SELECT f.myValue FROM c JOIN c.body['@internalId'] as f where c.id='SomeGuid'");
query.WithParameter("@internalId", strInternalGuid);
```

There are no errors, just no results.

If I use

```
new QueryDefinition("SELECT f.myValue FROM c JOIN c.body[@internalId] as f where c.id='SomeGuid'");
query.WithParameter("@internalId", strInternalGuid);
```

It throws an exception saying `incorrect syntax near '@internalId'`.

If the quotes are moved into the `WithParameter`, such as `query.WithParameter("@internalId", "'" + strInternalGuid + "'");` it produces the same syntax issue exception.

What needs to be modified to have the `@internalId` parameter work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are only meant for property values and not property keys. Thus you won't be able to get this query to work using `WithParameter`.

What you could do is make use of LINQ where you can make a query like:

```cs
var feed = container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<MyClass>()
    .Where(x => x.id == myId)
    .Select(x => x.body[myGuid].myValue)
    .ToFeedIterator();
```

Otherwise you'll need to sanitize the parameter yourself.